# Rails app on github – how secure is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, open-source

I'm going to upload the app, I've been working on, on the Github and make it public. The app is a website, which is on Rails. The question is – how secure is that? Isn't making my app's code public increase the chance of breaking in?

Comment: I think it's a good exercise in security. If you can make your source code public and *still* protect against attacks, you're doing something right.

Comment: Just be sure you don’t have any passwords or secret keys in your repo—though that should be avoided even if it isn’t public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' source code is open source / public anyway, so if you're referring to someone finding a "backdoor" or something, surely it would have been done already?

--

**Parts Of The Pie**

The real question of uploading your code to `github` is whether **your** application is secure by doing it. This is more a question of data integrity than source code "secrets", and as `@Andrew Marshall` mentioned in the comments, will be more dependent on you protecting your API keys & other authentication details, than it will be about minimizing the threat of security compromise.

> The other thing to remember is the [modularity of Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programmingr_programming),
>   from a dependency perspective. **The *real* value of an app is its
>   community** - the people who care about uploading new content to it.

This means your database, partner applications, on-site experience & "marketing" are worth *far more* than your bare source code. Sure, the source is important, but it's just one part of the pie ;)

You'll be much better focusing on your stack (to make it extensible), your application's relevance to your community, and how you're able to extend the functionality with partner services

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you secure your website to start. People can see all of your routes, so you need to protect restricted routes with before_action. If you have some kind of backdoor, they can see that too, so don't have one. If you follow good password encryption and login practices, you should be fine. The big file I would leave off Github is config/secrets.yml (as the name implies). But either way, most people aren't going to stumble across or care about reading your code, unless you advertise the link somewhere.